# Some question regarding basic measure theory

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $r_n$ is a sequence of real numbers such that
$0<r_1<r_2<r_3< ....$ Let $n(r)$ be the number of $r_i$'s 
less than $r$. Suppose $\sum_{n \geq 1} r_n^{- \beta} < \infty.$ 
Could someone please explain me how we obtain the following equalities?
$$
\sum_{n \geq 1} r_n^{- \beta} = \int_0^{\infty} r^{- \beta} \ dn(r)
= \beta \int_0^{\infty} r^{- \beta - 1} n(r) dr.
$$
Thanks!

Comment: The first writes the sum as a Stieltjes integral, since $n(r)$ is locally constant except at the points $r_k$ where it jumps up by $1$; the second is integration by parts.

Comment: One needs to show that $n(T)/T^\beta$ tends to $0$ as $T\to\infty$; this isn't hard from the hypotheses, but it's necessary to make disappear the boundary term arising from integration by parts.

Comment: Tom: if you don't get the first equality, you should go back and look at the definition of a (Riemann)-Stieltjes integral. This follows directly from that definition, so this is a great motivated learning moment!

Comment: @GregMartin I will! Thank you very much!